# Waxed cheese oozing oil

Tags: cheese

I have waxed cheddar and Gruyere, using black cheese wax, for about 4 months. When I turned it, I notice oil oozing. The Gruyere was from Bavaria.  How and why does this happen through the wax?

Answer (score 2):

The cheese is or has been too warm.

Cheese must be kept cool to cold.

Incidentally you cannot get Gruyere from Bavaria.

Gruyere is an address in yes but from no.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your first and fourth sentences aren't really sentences; you should edit this to clarify what you mean.